# JavaScript addEventListener not working with mobile toggle menu

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript code not working.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>

let mobile = document.querySelector(".container");
mobile.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

But this JavaScript code are working fine.

```
    <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

What is the problem with the 1st code. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: In the case of `addEventListener` the function signature is `myFunction(/*Event obj*/ e)`. Also you can use `this` inside it to access the target element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `addEventListener` the function signature is `myFunction(/*Event obj*/ e)`. Also you can use `this` inside it to access the target element. Something likee this.

```js
let mobile = document.querySelector(".container");
mobile.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
  //toggle whole container
  this.classList.toggle("change");
  //or toggle each child
  //e.target.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
.change {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar1">bar1</div>
  <div class="bar2">bar2</div>
  <div class="bar3">bar3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **target** property of the Event interface is a reference to the object that dispatched the event. The event.target property can be used in order to implement event delegation.
And event.currentTarget is interesting to use when attaching the same event handler to several elements.

Modify the function to →

```
function myFunction(x) {
    x.currentTarget.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `x` variable in the first function is actually an event variable and not the `.container` element itself.

To access the `.container` element, you would need to adjust the code to the following:

```
function myFunction(x) {
    x.currentTarget.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

The `currentTarget` references the element that the click event originates from.